# Webpack configuration error on "devtool: 'source-map',"

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying text book react application following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-and-react-js-fullstack-application-7ad99139e95c). However, when I run the command `sh -c webpack --watch -d --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js` (`npm run-script watch` as mentioned in the tutorial) I am getting the following error.

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.
```

My webpack.config.js is as follows.

```
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/App.js',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Any idea where is the issue?

I am using Webpack 5.29.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`webpack --watch -d --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js` Here **-d** means the devtool option and it overrides the option that is given in the file. In webpack 5, you can't pass empty to devtool.

That was the issue.